# Add items to Kendo MultiSelect with no datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I wonder if there is a way to make `@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor()` with no datasource and add items to it dynamically, simillar to the input for adding tags here on StackOverflow?

It would accept a model property with type `IEnumerable`:

```
@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Tags)
```

and accept the values through `jQuery`, something like:

```
$("#Tags").items.add("tag1");
```

I would appreciate if someone can advise on other Kendo widgets that allow quickly add and delete items in multivalue input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add/insert new items to the dataSource that the multiselect uses and thus they will become part of the collection as the other initial items.

e.g.

var ms = $("#select").data('kendoMultiSelect');

ms.dataSource.insert(0,{text:"some text",value:"333"})

http://jsbin.com/uWEvulEn/2/edit

Comment: Is it possible to automatically select that new item? Did you try that, @GyuzalR?

Comment: Try    
   var arr = ms.value().slice(0);
                  arr.unshift("8");
                  ms.value(arr);

here is updated example:
http://jsbin.com/qeyibutona/1/edit